# Sending an app request from app

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an ios app, that i put facebook into.

I need to implement app requests - i wrote the code as given in the sample on the facebook developer page

and if i run through the debug, i do receive a request id - telling me the request was sent

as I am sending the request to my test user account, i check the notifications tab inside the facebook app in the device, and it doesnt have any requests from my app. **How come ?**

here is my code:

```
-(void)invite:(NSString *)message{
    if(![self isLoggedInWithFacebook]){
        self.isRequestingInvite = YES;
        self.inviteMessage = message;
        [self facebookPerformLoginWithLoginUI:YES];
    }
    [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:message
     title:nil
     parameters:nil
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the send request callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 LogInfo(@"urlParams:%@",urlParams);
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Send button
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSArray *to =[urlParams valueForKey:@"to"];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                     if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(appRequestSentTo:withID:)]){
                         [self.delegate appRequestSentTo:to withID:requestID];
                     }

                 }
             }
         }
     }];
    }


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    // Handle the user leaving the app while the Facebook login dialog is being shown
    // For example: when the user presses the iOS "home" button while the login dialog is active
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

note: facebook login works just fine